# How is persistence implemented in Dart?

Tags: web, programming-languages, persistence, dart, persistent-storage

Are there any APIs provided in the Dart language that implement persistence? I searched for persistence in the Dart website, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather unsecific question.

In the browser you can use what the browser offers (indexedDb, KeyValue store).
In Chrome packaged apps you can persist to a file on the client side too.
You can send data to a server and let persist in a file for the client.

On the server side you can persist to a file.
You can also use different kind of databases which store to a file as well.

Some information about a concrete use case would be helpful.